# Dynamic function calling with unknowin type and number of parameters in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I call functions of a `dll` with this way :-

```
typedef double(*GetMaxSampleFrequencyF)(void);                      
 GetMaxSampleFrequencyF freq;           
 freq =  (GetMaxSampleFrequencyF)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary,GetMaxSampleFrequencyF); 
 double x = freq();  

 typedef char* (*InitInstrument)(char* wAddress);      
 InitInstrument open;     
 open = (InitInstrument)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "InitInstrument");     
 open("com1");
```

But I can't do this for a huge number of functions so I want a way to do this dynamically however I already saved the name of functions, its return type, its parameters and types in a database.

Comment: Basically, you'd have to do at run time what the compiler does at compile time - use machine instructions to set up the call frame according to the calling convention of the target architecture. There's no quick and easy way, if that's what you are hoping for.

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: Look at the assembly instructions the compiler generates for a "normal" function call. You'd have to do the same, programmatically.